# Should "and" be on the following line?

Tags: writing

If a sentence contains the word "and" at a place where it needs to continue on the next line, should the "and" be put at the end of that line or at the beginning of the next line?

> Capturing a Performance Monitor log **and**
>   comparing it with baseline performance throughput [...]

or

> Capturing a Performance Monitor log
>   **and** comparing it with baseline performance throughput [...]

Comment: I don't think there are general rules for things like this, since typically you'd just write the entire paragraph as one "line" and let whatever is formatting it for display flow it to fit the space without regard for what the actual words are.

Comment: Given a choice, I'd slightly favour the second example **in your case**. This is because there's a slight hinting at a 'Capturing a Performance Monitor log and _ . _ . _ a graph of the system' type of coordination with an and that's not postponed. BTW, your example isn't strictly a sentence (but then why should one be limited to writing in sentences if one writes sensibly?)

Comment: If you're going to boldface **and**, you probly ought to put it on a line by itself, between the two conjuncts. That's the structure, after all, and you should make it clear wherever possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is either typesetting or style that is in question, but not the English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in English, we simply start a new line when we have no more room in the current line for extra words, barring the start of a new paragraph, heading, or list item.

If you consider the two pieces to be list items, then the *and* should either part of the last item, or (preferably), on its own. Capitalisation should be consistent among the list items (all initial-capitalised, or all initial-lower) with the exception that an *and* on its own may be lower-case as not a full list-item (or capitalised for emphasis, but not if bold or similar is allowed). Hence:

> - Capturing a Performance Monitor log
> - And comparing it with baseline performance throughput

Or

> - Capturing a Performance Monitor log
>
>   and
> - Comparing it with baseline performance throughput

If it's a sentence though (as you say), then you would ignore all of this, and just write until you run out of room on the page.

An exception is that with some very carefully typesetting, one may well consider the position of every line-break, much as one considers the choice of font, custom-kern particular letters, adjust leading on individual items, and so on. Such a case is an area where writing and graphic design interact with each other strongly, rather than normal writing.

Answer (score 0):

Like wobble said, there's no strict ruling for this as it would be all written on one line normally.

However, in a list, you should end the line with the 'and' and begin the next one with the verb as it is a new point or action e.g.

> Capturing a Performance Monitor log and
>
> comparing it with baseline performance throughput [...]

Might be best to put 'and' on a middle line e.g.

> Capturing a Performance Monitor log
>
> and
>
> comparing it with baseline performance throughput [...]

Comment: As my comment shows, I disagree. Though I wouldn't usually be this precious when writing.

Comment: [Throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput) refers to bandwidth and has a specific meaning different from *throughout*.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. You do learn something new every day!

Comment: I don't think the "and" belongs on the second line unless this is an explicit list. Having "and\n" primes the reader to continue reading for the rest of the sentence. If there is a an explicit list they are already doing that (and the "and" is probably extraneous.)